# Does ffmpeg support yv12?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've got raw `YUV` file that is `YV12` format. 
`YV12` is not `YUV420P`, nor `I420`.
`X264` can process it, but `ffmpeg` can't.

```
x264 --input-res 1280x720 --fps 25 --input-csp yv12 --output 2.mp4 2.yuv
--this runs correctly, and color is correct!

ffmpeg -c rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yv12 -r 25 -i 2.yuv 2.mp4
--there is an error: No such pixel format: yv12

ffmpeg -c rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -i 2.yuv 2.mp4
--this can run, but color is NOT correct!

ffmpeg -pix_fmts
--there is no YV12 format in the result list.


ffmpeg version N-81516-gbe07c25 Copyright (c) 2000-2016
```

So, could anyone tell whether `ffmpeg` supports `YV12` or not? If yes, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

YV12 is equivalent to YVU420(P/I), which ffmpeg doesn't appear to read directly.

Use a filter to swap the planes:

```
ffmpeg -c rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -i 2.yuv -vf shuffleplanes=0:2:1 2.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

ffplay does not support YV12，use ffmpeg to transcode：

```
ffmpeg -vtag YV12 -f rawvideo -s 1280x720 -i cam001  cam001.png
```

Comment: Haven't tried this because I've lost my yv12 source file.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Android and ffmpeg have different meanings for YUV420P and YV12. The standard Y-U-V pixel arrangement for YV12 is (which android seems to not follow):

[image]

while YUV420 has V and U planes interchanged. So you should be able to play YV12 content with ffplay using (as Gyan mentioned in other answer):

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 640x480 -vf shuffleplanes=0:2:1 -i record_640x480_1.yv12
```

The shuffleplanes filter tells ffplay to interchange the U and V planes before rendering.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/recommended-8-bit-yuv-formats-for-video-rendering?redirectedfrom=MSDN#yv12) for other formats' pixel arrangement and [ffmpeg site](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#shuffleplanes) for more info on shuffle planes filter.

## Old Answer:

According to [this](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/av/services/camera/libcameraservice/api1/client2/Parameters.cpp#180) android code, YV12 is equivalent to YUV420P and yuv420p is supported by ffmpeg/ffplay.

so you should be able to play your yv12 content using:

```
 ffplay  -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size <wxh> -i <file name>
```

Tested with [this](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/cts/tests/tests/media/res/raw/video_176x144_yv12.raw) android sample yuv12 content using ffplay version 4.3.1.

Comment: The OP has already checked `yuv420p`, and says *this can run, but color is NOT correct*